# Regular Expressions. Delete the whole string if there is nothing after ":" symbol

Tags: python, regex

For example, my text file is an log file.

```
...
User1: hi
User2: 
User1: whoops, forgot to tell you
User2: ok
User1: 
User2:
User1: test
```

Result I want:

```
...
User1: hi
User1: whoops, forgot to tell you
User2: ok
User1: test
```

I've tried `^[^:]*\S`, but that only selects everything before ":" symbol.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\S` couls also match an other char than `:`

You could match the `:` instead and then match whitespace chars except newline till the end of the line.

```
^[^:]*:[^\S\r\n]*\r?\n
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[^:]*:` 0+ occurrences of any char except `:`, then match `:`
- `[^\S\r\n]*` 0+ occurrences of a whitespace char except a newline
- `\r?\n` Match a newline (Or [assert](https://regex101.com/r/OECFHU/1) the end of the line using an alternation)

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3VeMP3/1)

Note that `[^:]` could also match a newline.

Answer (score 0):

You might do this without `re`, following way

```
text = '''User1: hi
User2: 
User1: whoops, forgot to tell you
User2: ok
User1: 
User2:
User1: test'''
print(*[line for line in text.split('\n') if line.rstrip().split(':', 1)[-1]], sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
User1: hi
User1: whoops, forgot to tell you
User2: ok
User1: test
```

I assume all lines have at least one `:`, then for each line I:

- jettison trailing whitespaces
- split at first `:`
- take line only if what was after `:` is not empty str